# glfwSwapInterval(1) fails to enable vsync?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

`glfwSwapInterval(1)` doesn't seem to be working for me. If I force VSync in CCC or `setVerticalSyncEnabled(true)` in SFML my fps drops to 60, but GLFW just keeps running at 9000 fps. Am I going about this the wrong way or is GLFW bugged?

Comment: What GPU are you using? GLFW FAQ [says something](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#33__why_doesnt_glfwswapinterval_work) about `glfwSwapInterval` not working on some ATI drivers. I've never used GLFW, but could you perhaps try directly calling `(PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT")`?

Comment: @EdwardA yes it ATI. Why would it work in SFML then though? `wglSwapIntervalEXT` works for some reason... So GLFW is bugged?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, although if `wglSwapIntervalEXT` works it sure means it has something to do with GLFW. You could try downloading the [GLFW source](http://www.glfw.org/download.html), compile your program alongside with it and put a breakpoint @ [line 831 window.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw-legacy/blob/master/lib/window.c#L831) and [line 1638 win32_window.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw-legacy/blob/master/lib/win32/win32_window.c#L1638) to see whats really happening. It could be one of those if checks failing.

Comment: Well... `_glfwIsCompositionEnabled()` returns true. Oh well gotta do  it manually then. Thanks :)

Comment: I see the same issue on Intel HD 4600 graphics on Windows7. So it is not a strictly ATI problem.

Comment: @EdwardA [This GLFW issue](http://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/148) was fixed in release 3.1.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well looks like GLFW doesn't want to turn VSync on when desktop compositing is enabled. If you want VSync anyway this will work on Windows:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    // Turn on vertical screen sync under Windows.
    // (I.e. it uses the WGL_EXT_swap_control extension)
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)(int interval);
    PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC wglSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;
    wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");
    if(wglSwapIntervalEXT)
        wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);
#endif
```

For other OSs google will help you.

Comment: This fix did not work on my Intel HD 4600, as the proc address was 0. But configuring GLFW3 to use GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL did.

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild GLFW3 with the GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL option.

See `glfw/src/config.h`

The GLFW docs warn about jitter problems, but I don't see those myself.

Comment: With release 3.1.2 this flag was removed; however, the fix is also in, so it isn't needed any longer :)

Answer (score 2):

Found that glfwSwapInterval needed calling again after changing between window and full screen mode, otherwise the framerate would be massive.

```
if (fullScreen)
            {
                glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, monitor, 0, 0, monitorMode->width, monitorMode->height, monitorMode->refreshRate);

                // Added to fix framerate to vertical refresh //
                glfwSwapInterval(1);
            }
            else
            {
                glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, NULL, 0, 0, monitorMode->width, monitorMode->height, monitorMode->refreshRate);
            }
```